# How to pass parameters into your ETL job?

Tags: kiba-etl

I am building an ETL which will be run on different sources, by a variable.

How can I execute my job (rake task)

```
Kiba.run(Kiba.parse(IO.read(etl_file),etl_file))
```

and pass in parameters for my `etl_file` to then use for its sources?

`source MySourceClass(variable_from_rake_task)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of Kiba here.

EDIT: the solution below still applies, but if you need more flexibility, you can use Kiba.parse with a block to get more flexibility. See https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki/Considerations-for-running-Kiba-jobs-programmatically-(from-Sidekiq,-Faktory,-Rake,-...) for a detailed explanation.

Since you are using a Rake task (and not calling Kiba in a parallel environment, like Resque or Sidekiq), what you can do right now is leverage `ENV` variables, like this:

```
CUSTOMER_IDS=10,11,12 bundle exec kiba etl/upsert-customers.etl
```

Or, if you are using a rake task you wrote, you can do:

```
task :upsert_customers => :environment do
  ENV['CUSTOMER_IDS'] = [10, 11, 12].join(',)
  etl_file = 'etl/upsert-customers.etl'
  Kiba.run(Kiba.parse(IO.read(etl_file),etl_file))
end
```

Then in `upsert-customers.etl`:

```
# quick parsing
ids = ENV['CUSTOMER_ID'].split(',').map { |c| Integer(c) }

source Customers, ids: ids
```

As I stated before, this will only work for command line mode, where `ENV` can be leveraged safely.

For parallel executions, please indeed track https://github.com/thbar/kiba/issues/18 since I'm going to work on it.

Let me know if this properly answers your need!

Comment: Clever, why didn't I think of that! Thank you!

Comment: Well I wouldn't say this feels super natural, yet I've been using this technique previously with activewarehouse-etl for years. It avoids cluttering the command line with very specific switches that end up being not flexible enough. Glad I could help!

Comment: I've edited the answer since a second solution now exists.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is tracked here https://github.com/thbar/kiba/issues/18 and already asked here [Pass Parameters to Kiba run Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332099/pass-parameters-to-kiba-run-method)

Comment: I answered in a separate reply, since I think there is a better answer in your current context (calling from rake task).